# Sum Infinite Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, law-of-large-numbers, jensen-inequality

Let's say we generate $n$ samples independently from two independent distributions $X$ and $Y$. We know that the following is true from Jensen's Inequality:
$$\
E\left[\min\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i, \sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i\right)\right] \leq \min\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}E[X_i], \sum_{i=1}^{n}E[Y_i]\right)
$$
I was wondering what happens if $n \to \infty$. Precisely,
$$\
\lim_{n\to \infty}E\left[\min\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i, \sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i\right)\right] = \lim_{n\to \infty}E\left[n\times \min\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{n}, \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i}{n}\right)\right]
$$
From Strong Law of Large Numbers we have,
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}E\left[n\times \min\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{n}, \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i}{n}\right)\right]&=\lim_{n\to \infty}E[n\times \min(\mu_X, \mu_Y)]\\&=\lim_{n\to \infty}n\times \min(\mu_X, \mu_Y)
\end{align}
For the second term,
$$\
\min\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}E[X_i], \sum_{i=1}^{n}E[Y_i]\right)=n\times \min(\mu_X, \mu_Y)
$$
I know that the above results don't mean much as we have $\lim_{n\to \infty}n\times constant$. However, my intuition says that for large values of $n$ both the terms should be pretty close. Can you please explain if my intuition is actually correct? Can you please give a proof for the same or a counter-example?

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @joriki thanks I will make the edit.

Comment: @joriki what's your say on this? This problem deals with Pseudo-Regret vs True-Regret in Multi-Armed Bandits

Comment: One example scenario is when $\{X_i\}$ are i.i.d. Gaussian $N(0,1)$ and $Y_i=-X_i$ for all $i$.  Then $\min[\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i] , \sum_{i=1}^n E[Y_i]]=0$ for all $n$ but $E[\min[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i, \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i]] = -E[|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i|] = -\sqrt{n}E[|X_1|]$ and goes to $-\infty$.

Comment: @Michael That's interesting. But, $X$ and $Y$ are not independent in your example. Can you think of an example when they are independent?

Comment: Almost the same example works, see my answer below.  I also observe that your work does not require $\{X_i\}$ and $\{Y_i\}$ to be independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Example:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent Gaussian $N(0,1)$. Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be independent and i.i.d. Gaussian $N(0,1)$. Then
$$ \min\left[\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i], \sum_{j=1}^nE[Y_j]\right] = 0 \quad \forall n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$
However, $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ has the same distribution as $\sqrt{n}X$ and so for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ we have by independence of $\{X_i\}$ and $\{Y_i\}$:
\begin{align}
E\left[\min\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i, \sum_{j=1}^n Y_j \right] \right] &= E\left[\min\left[\sqrt{n}X, \sqrt{n}Y\right]\right] \\
&=\sqrt{n}\underbrace{E[\min[X,Y]]}_{<0}
\end{align}
and so this goes to $-\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

According to Wolfram-Alpha we have
$$ E[\min[X,Y]] = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \approx -0.56419 $$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+int+1%2F%282+pi%29+min%28x%2Cy%29exp%28-x%5E2%2F2%29exp%28-y%5E2%2F2%29%2C+x%3D-infty..infty%2C+y%3D-infty..infty

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Btw, why did you remove that part where you pointed out the mistake in my work?

Comment: Just to make my answer shorter, also, we would actually need something like Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem to justify pushing the limit through the expectation.  Assuming we can push the limit through, your work essentially shows $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{E[\min[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i, \sum_{j=1}^n Y_j]]}{n} = \min[E[X], E[Y]]=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\min[\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i], \sum_{j=1}^n E[Y_j]]}{n} $$ but the gap in the numerators can grow large (though it must grow sublinearly with $n$).

Comment: Thanks for the details. "though it must grow sublinearly with $n$" is quite interesting.